# Team System web access rights

Tags: tfs

We're using team system to control our developement (product backlog items, sprint backlog items etc).  It's a pretty nice tool but we wanted to allow other users to be able add bugs and new feature suggestions WITHOUT letting them mess with the actual development bits.

I can set these guys up so they add the work items they need but I can't see a way to block access to the bits I don't want them to edit/view.  Has anyone else seen this?  Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using TFS 2010?  If so, you can simply add them to the **Work Item View Only Users** group.  This will grant them access to create new work items and to view/edit any work items they've created (but not others).  Check out this link for [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx).

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thanks for the response.  We are currently on 2008 but are planning to move to 2010 soon.  If 2010 supports this, that would be another great reason to accelerate the process.

Comment: Another good reason to migrate to TFS2010 is native Scrum template and **Urban Turtle** (http://urbanturtle.com).  According to Microsoft, the premier Agile tooling for TFS is Urban Turtle. Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Brian Harry, who is the Product Unit Manager for Team Foundation Server, said about Urban Turtle: **"...awesome Scrum experience for TFS."** You can read Brian Harry's blog post at the following URL: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/01/05/urban-turtle-for-scrum-and-tfs.aspx